# Investigating a segmentation fault running QT-Wayland Compositor

Tags: strace

Can someone please interpret the last a few lines here? I don't think there is anything wrong until suddenly segmentation fault occurs.

```
lstat64("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=61440, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib/qt5", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib/qt5/plugins", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/wayland-graphics-integration-server", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/wayland-graphics-integration-server/libwayland-egl.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=22116, ...}) = 0
stat64("/usr/share/qt5/examples/wayland/minimal-qml/wayland-graphics-integration-server/.", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/share/qt5/examples/wayland/minimal-qml/wayland-graphics-integration-server", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 21
fstat64(21, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents64(21, /* 3 entries */, 32768)  = 88
getdents64(21, /* 0 entries */, 32768)  = 0
close(21)                               = 0
lstat64("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/share", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/share/qt5", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/share/qt5/examples", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/share/qt5/examples/wayland", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/share/qt5/examples/wayland/minimal-qml", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/share/qt5/examples/wayland/minimal-qml/wayland-graphics-integration-server", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/share/qt5/examples/wayland/minimal-qml/wayland-graphics-integration-server/libwayland-egl.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47168, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/qt5/examples/wayland/minimal-qml/wayland-graphics-integration-server/libwayland-egl.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 21
fcntl64(21, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)        = 0
fstat64(21, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47168, ...}) = 0
fstat64(21, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47168, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 47168, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 21, 0) = 0xafcbc000
close(21)                               = 0
munmap(0xafcbc000, 47168)               = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x4} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: What kind of interpretation are you asking for?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the reason for seg fault

Comment: `SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x4}` says the process tried to access memory address `0x4` and got a segfault for it. Probably a null pointer dereference in struct form, i.e. `ptr->field` where `ptr` is null.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Address 0x4 is definitely not right.

Comment: Was this an unmodified example? If so, could you please file a bug report at bugreports.qt.io?

Comment: @bobbaluba done! https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66996